# How to Programatically determine Headers for HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, bots, webautomation

I dabble in coding some bots/web automation software  quite a bit. In order to do what I do, I simply sniff headers with Fiddler and manually add them to the request. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this, perhaps where I can just specify the URL for a GET request which will automatically determine the needed headers and add them.

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm looking for a way to create cleaner, simpler code, and this would help a lot.

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Not quite sure what you are getting at.  Maybe an example of what header and when you would grab it would help.  `HttpWebRequest` had a `Headers` property that can be used to add headers, [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers.aspx).

Comment: Its not going to get much simpler then `myRequest.Headers.Add("MyHeader","MyValue");`